# Sending SOAP http response in one package

Tags: java, web-services, soap

We have a Java web service with `document style` and `http protocol`. Local this service works smoothly and fast (~ 6ms). But calling the service-methods from remote takes over 200ms.

One main reason for this delay is that the

1. server sends first the response http header,
2. the client sends in return a ACK and
3. then again the server sends the response http body.

This second step where the client sends the ACK costs the most time, almost the whole 200ms. I would like to avoid this step and save the time.

So that's why my question: Is it possible to send the whole response in one package? And how and where do I configure that?

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not fully understanding the question.

Why is the server sending the first message? Shouldn't the client be requesting for a web service via HTTP initially?

From what I understand, SOAP requests are wrapped within an http message. HTTP messages assumes a TCP connection and requires a response. This suggests that a client must respond when the server sends an http header.

Basically whatever one end sends to another, the other end must reply. The ACK return from you step 2 will always be present.

EDIT:

I think the reason for the difference in time when requesting via local and remote is simply the routing that happens in the real network versus on your local machine. It's not the number of steps taken in your SOAP request and response.

Comment: "Basically whatever one end sends to another, the other end must reply". Yes, that's why I want to send the reply in one step and not in two. So if I send the response in one package, I will get one ACK, and not two (so save one).

Comment: "Shouldn't the client be requesting for a web service via HTTP initially?" The client does requesting via HTTP initially.

Comment: "the reason for the difference in time when requesting via local and remote is simply the routing". Can't be, I tested it f.e. a socket server needs pretty much the same time for local and remote.